# Html Style Attribute Double

Tags: html, colors, attributes, styles

I am a beginner coder and I want to know how this is solved:

```
<a href="link-example"><font size="6"><font style="color:limegreen"></a>
(8 lines)
</font>
```

How do you make it so

```
<font style="color:limegreen">
```

applies to all 9 lines?

Comment: Your tag nesting is off, you're closing `</font>` after the tag it is contained in is closed (`</a>`). Also, the number of closing `</font>`s should be the same as the number of corresponding opening tags.

And then, you shouldn't be using `<font>` at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree and I realised that after learning way more html.

Comment: I use an external CSS file now that I've learned CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it:

```
<a href="link-example" style="color:limegreen"><font size="6">
(8 lines)
</font></a>
```